# Get Item Name from ListView using setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

**Hello world**:

I need your help again, i have an listview with onclick event but i need to get item name from the clicked item.

This is what i have at the moment ...

```
Product_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

               final int selected_row = position;
               final Product user = (Product) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

               AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(nuevo_pedido.this);

               alert.setTitle("Cantidad: ");

                final NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(nuevo_pedido.this);
                String[] nums = new String[11];
                for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
                       nums[i] = Integer.toString(i);

                np.setMinValue(0);
                np.setMaxValue(nums.length-1);
                np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
                np.setDisplayedValues(nums);
                np.setValue(0);


                alert.setView(np);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  // Do something with value!

                    int valor = np.getValue();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Valor: " + valor + " Producto: " + user + " Usr: " + extraData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                  }
                });

                alert.show();
    }

});
```

When my code is running all its OK, but send something what is not the name.

**chintan.khetiya.sqlite.cursor.Product@40ec4d88**

Suggestions ??

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `lv.getItemAtPosition(position)` to get the text.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
    long arg3) 
{
   String name = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
}
});
```

Take a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29

Comment: He already is using that. The problem is that he is trying to display his "Product" object as a String

Comment: That code send the same result...

chintan.khetiya.sqlite.cursor.Product@40ec4df8

Answer (score 1):

```
Product_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
```

we can get object from adapterView as

```
final Product user = (Product)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Now, you get

> name of product by getter.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the object **product**, it would be possible not catch the name attribute through a getter:
**product.getName()**

Or the problem is something else?